# Uninstall of dependent operators

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise, operator-sdk

The olm-book mentions about dependency resolution during install time, can you please also describe how uninstall/cleanup works.

Does the OLM keep reference counter of dependent operators when its a shared dependency ?
How to cleanup the dependent operators and when to do this?

olm-book : https://operator-framework.github.io/olm-book/docs/operator-dependencies-and-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

I can explain on how `operator-sdk cleanup` [command](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/cli/operator-sdk_cleanup/) works while uninstalling an operator bundle/packagemanifest managed by OLM.

The first step of the process is to identify and remove the [subscription](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/concepts/crds/subscription/) so that we stop any upgrades or further installs. Followed by this, we get the [ClusterServiceVersion](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/concepts/crds/clusterserviceversion/) for the particular operator which is to be uninstalled from the subscription itself. When OLM creates resources it adds owner references/owner label to every namespaced/cluster scoped resource specified in the CSV. Hence, when a CSV is deleted the OLM garbage collector identifies the dependent resources through the owner references and deletes them.

If you want to cleanup the operator manually, I would suggest to just remove the ClusterServiceVersion referenced in installplan and leave it to the OLM and Kubebuilder GC to delete the resources.